# How to keep updated multiple postgres databases, tables and functions wise

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design, relational-database

i have multiple databases running **postgres 9.4**  on different locations, and each one has the same table structure and functions wise, base on your experience, what is the best way to update their tables or functions to each one of them, every time the development team makes a change

*Ex: if they add a new table or made changes to a function, how can i update all the databases, right now i update them one by one.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider adopting a database refactoring/migration tool like [`liquibase`](http://www.liquibase.org).

`Liquibase` creates a table in your database that keeps the database version and the changes that have been executed already. It provides an xml-based scripting language that can be used smoothly with source versioning between several members of the team, and it supports `PostgreSQL` perfectly, along with transactions and rollbacks.

The tool checks the current version of your target database, and it executes against it only the necessary changes that are required to update it to the latest version.

`Liquibase` also offers a `maven` plugin and/or an `ant` task enabling the development team to integrate its execution as a step in the build process.

Alternatively you can consider also [`Flyway`](https://flywaydb.org/) that offers all the necessary features also.

Comment: Thanks a lot, exactly what i was looking for

Comment: @PaulMB Do you need any further clarifications? Or you could accept this answer to your question?